Finding the balanced direction at every step - from a sub-routes array
I have an array of sub-routes that are inside a defined bbox.
I want to navigate from the start point towards the end point without colliding with obstacles (which is marked in black).
Since I have thousands of sub-routes in this field, and all of them have different lengths, I want to do this by choosing the balanced direction at each step.
That is to browse directions until I reach the target area.
What I tried:
I built a function that every time looks for the points from each route that are really close (up to a distance of 1) to the current point where I am. For these points I calculate their slope towards the next point in their array, finally I calculate the equal direction and take a step in its direction. And so again and again until the destination is reached. I couldn't get it right. I got bad directions. Something in this algorithm didn't work well
Another thing I tried, I calculated the directions of each track and tried to build an algorithm that calculates the balanced direction of each cell in which a track passes. But once again I got not good results at all
I would be happy for help and guidance in the code and the solution approach
Thank you very much everyone
#1:
enter image description here
#2:
enter image description here
#3 the last image:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry if I misunderstand you problem, but if you already have the map and want to find a path from start to goal, why not use A* or dijkstra. what is the purpose of the route and subroute?
